# deserialize json to C# classed not working

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, json.net

using Nwetonsoft dll

**JSON format**

```
{
   "PersistData":{
        "method":["SetColorPersist","SetColorPersist","SetColorPersist"],
        "per":["BF0ECF","78F77A","0918B8"],
        "Source":["0","0","0"]}
}
```

**C# class**

```
[Serializable]
 public class PersistData
    {
        [SerializeField]
        public string[] Method;
        [SerializeField]
        public string[] Per;
        [SerializeField]
        public string[] Source;
    }
```

**deserialize**

```
public PersistData persistObj = new PersistData();
string json = Obj.data.ToString();
persistObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PersistData>(json);
```

tried with unity jsonutility its not supporting array JSON.
newton JSON not deserializing JSON to Class

Please provide some solution that I can make it work. I tried all solutions mostly.

Comment: C# is case sensitive. You use both upper- and lowercase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add outer class OutPersistData to wrap PersistData like this

```
class OutPersistData
{
    public PersistData PersistData { get; set; }
}
```

Then deserialize the OutPersistData to an object

```
var persistObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OutPersistData>(json);
```

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Because the json hierarchy isn't correct, if you want to use `PersistData` as Deserialize target, drop the outer annotation in json would make it work.

```
{
    "method":["SetColorPersist","SetColorPersist","SetColorPersist"],
    "per":["BF0ECF","78F77A","0918B8"],
    "Source":["0","0","0"]
}
```

Alternatively, you can create outer class to wrap `PersistData`, then you can use the origin json content to deserialize.

**OuterClass.cs**

```
public class OuterClass
{
    public PersistData PersistData { get; set; }
}
```

Remember to change the deserialize target to `OuterClass` if you choose secondary solution.

```
var outerClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OuterClass>(json);
```